# Triggering local sonarqube scan using Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to be able to run SonarQube scans locally, prior to committing and having to check our Jenkins for the results. I have setup Sonar-Scanner via Docker desktop and if I run the following command from commandline, scan is triggered and results visible in my localhost:

```
sonar-scanner \
-Dsonar.projectKey=SonarQube_Locally_Test \
-Dsonar.sources=. \
-Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
-Dsonar.login=<token>
```

Now I do not want to copy paste the command every time I want to run the scan so I made a .sh file which I can run directly from my IDE (So far that works as well).

Now my teams want to have that working from a Makefile, so I (wrongly) though I could just do the following:

```
Sonar_Run:
    sonar-scanner \
    -Dsonar.projectKey=SonarQube_Locally_Test \
    -Dsonar.sources=. \
    -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
    -Dsonar.login=<token>
.PHONY: Sonar_Run
```

But this results in "make: sonar-scanner: No such file or directory"

I am guessing MAKE does not have access to environment variables where the path for sonar-scanner is stored.

Is there any quick fix have MAKE able to run sonar-scanner like this?

*edit*
When running:

```
path:
    echo ${PATH}
```

it returns:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

When I run `echo $path` from terminal I get:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Users/ronaldkoornneef/Downloads/sonar-scanner-4.7.0.2747-macosx/bin`

So it appears my added path for sonar-scanner is not seen by running the Makefile

As a workaround I have placed the SonarQube folder in the root of my project, eliminating the need for PATH, but this means that every project will need this inside, instead of in 1 shared location outside any project.

Comment: `make` should inherit `PATH` from the shell it was invoked from, so this is weird.

Comment: The only other thing I can add is that `make` by default uses `sh` as shell while you are very likely using something different. Are you maybe invoking `make` via some chain of commands by which it never sees the usual `bash` (or similar) interactive shell init? Can you also show what `$(info $(shell whoami))` tells you?

Comment: Are you setting the make variable `PATH` in your makefile?  That will override the setting inherited from the parent.  Are you resetting the make variable `SHELL` in your makefile?  To what?  Most likely you have a discordance between your `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` files, and/or you've set the `ENV` environment variable to something that doesn't fully configure your `PATH`.  However it's odd because a simple command like the one you show shouldn't even invoke the shell: it should use the fast path and just run the command.  Unless `<token>` contains special characters.

Comment: @Vroomfondel and @MadScientist , the invocation is very straightforward but perhaps there might be some issue in it. I am running it directly from PyCharm (not using venv), from my MAC (bigSur) and the makefile is very simple. It only contains a handful of commands to trigger unittest, githooks and pre-commit nothing fancy. All commands are simply run by clicking them, nothing is called somewhere from a different location. Since I'm using mac, my terminal shell is zsh.

When I run ```$(info$(whoami))``` in a make command from ide, I simply get my user back. I will need to check the profile..